# Display prices on frontend even if base is zero

Tags: customer, frontend, customer-group, pricing

I am using my store as B2B.
I have prices per customer according to their customer group pricing.
My problem is that i dont have in all retail prices to add in base price.
So base price is zero in most references.
If i have base price, magento will display base price crossed and then the customer groups price.
If i dont have base price and i have customer group price, it will display zero.
I need to display only the customers group price ignoring base price. Not even crossed if it exists.
I have searched a lot but i couldnt find an extension that supports that.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding a block displaying only the products different than $0.

In your Magento Admin > Content > Blocks > Add New Block

Click on "Show / Hide Editor" button, then "Insert Widget" button.

In "Widget Type", you select "Catalog Product List", complete the form as per your necessity and set the condition, where the product price is not equals to zero.

Will  be like the below image.

[image]

With that, you just need to add the block on your homepage or at your best convenience.

Comment: Hello.I finally found a solution with an extension MageWorxCustomer Group Prices that deos this for anyone that may need that. Thank you though.